# Amp XHR Form Pages Redirect

Tags: amp-html

I created amp form.
When I click on Butona, I check the values in the form from different pages.
I have no problems here.
If all the data is correct I want to direct a unique adrese.
How can I direct the visitor when the form is positive?

```
 <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
 <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>

<form method="POST" action-xhr="//example.com/control" target="_top">
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="3" />
...
<button type="submit" class="btn">Check and go</button>
<div submit-success>
   <template type="amp-mustache">
       {{message}}
   </template>
</div>
<div submit-error>
   <template type="amp-mustache">
       {{message}}
   </template>
</div>
</form>
```

I am showing the requests coming with Json in the variable named message.
I want to forward a different address instead of showing the last message. Is this possible with AMP?

Comment: Please add your codes

Comment: I add the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **PHP** in the backend to control the submitted values of the XHR form, then you can simply follow this:

```
if( !empty($_POST) ){

    //--YOUR OTHER CODING--
    //...........

    $domain_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
    $redirect_url = 'https://example.com/forms/thank-you/'; //-->MUST BE 'https://';

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.ampproject.org");
    header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: ".$domain_url);

    if( isEmailAlreadyExist($_POST['email']) ){ //-->SAMPLE Valiation!
        //-->Any 40X status code! 
        //Reference-1: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/6058
        //Reference-2: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-response-code.php
        header("HTTP/1.0 412 Precondition Failed", true, 412);
        echo json_encode(array('errmsg'=>'This email already exist!'));
        die();
    }else{
        //--Assuming all validations are good here--
        if( empty($redirect_url) ){
            header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
        }else{
            header("AMP-Redirect-To: ".$redirect_url);
            header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Redirect-To, AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
        }
        echo json_encode(array('successmsg'=>'My success message. [It will be displayed shortly(!) if with redirect]'));
        die();
    }
}
```

There is a [limitation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/dynamic/amp-form#redirecting-after-a-submission) that the redirect URL must be absolute **HTTPS URL** otherwise AMP will throw an error and redirection won't happen.
Hopefully it will help ;)

Answer (score 0):

one must use :

```
header('AMP-Redirect-To: https://...');
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin, AMP-Redirect-To");
```

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using

```
action-xhr="//example.com/control"
```

Use

```
action="//example.com/control"
```

And let the URL (//example.com/control) redirect the user

Comment: This is not the answer to this question!